# Angular - View taking long to show changes and performance issues

Tags: css, angular, performance, ionic-framework

I am making an Ionic Angular App.

I have a page which shows a spinner until the call to an API REST is finished to retrieved the required data.

My problem is that after the call is done, the spinner dissapears, as expected, but the data takes like 2 seconds to be displayed on screen. I am using change detection but even if I turn it off, it'll still do the same. This data is an array.

My code is the following

**home.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="loading else show">
   <spinner [purple]="true" class="veritcal-center"></spinner>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #show>
    <div>
      <ng-template #mobile>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let work of works">
          <book-home-card-mobile [work]="work">
          </book-home-card-mobile>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

**home.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HomePage {
  public works: Array<Work>;
  public loading: boolean;

  constructor(
    private worksService: WorksService,
    private detector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    this.works = [];
    this.loading = true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getWorks();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.detector.detach();
  }

  private getWorks(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.detector.detectChanges();

    this.worksService.getWorks('newer', 0)
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        response.forEach((work: Work) => this.works.push(work));
        this.loading = false;
        this.detector.detectChanges();
      });
  }
}
```

**book-home-card-mobile.html**

```
<div class="d-inline-block">
  <ion-card [class.view]="overlay" [class.waves-effect]="waves" [class.overlay]="overlay" class="material-tooltip-main"
    [class.xl-card]="main" [class.sm-card]="!main" data-toggle="tooltip" [title]="tooltip">
    <div class="d-inline-block portrait" [class.waves-effect]="details" [style.cursor]="details ?  'pointer' : 'auto'">
      <img [src]="work.image">
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="overlay" class="mask flex-center rgba-stylish-slight"></div>

    <div class="d-inline-block details">

      <div class="details-container">
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-title style="white-space: nowrap; 
          overflow: hidden;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;" [class.waves-effect]="details" [style.cursor]="details ?  'pointer' : 'auto'">
            {{ work.title }}</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>

        <div class="icons">
          <div class="d-inline-block icon">
            <ion-icon class="icon-card" name="eye"></ion-icon> <span class="amount">{{ visits }}</span>
          </div>

          <div class="d-inline-block icon">
            <ion-icon name="chatbubbles"></ion-icon> <span class="amount">{{ commentsCount }}</span>
          </div>

          <div class="d-inline-block icon">
            <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon> <span class="amount">{{ likes }}</span>
          </div>

        </div>

        <ng-container *ngIf="ellipsis else noEllipsis2">
          <div class="description" ellipsis [ellipsis-content]="work.description"></div>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-template #noEllipsis2>
          <div class="description" [class.ellipsis-scroll]="!ellipsis" s>
            {{ work.description }}
          </div>
        </ng-template>

        <ion-card-header>
          <div class="caret"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></div>

          <ion-card-subtitle style="white-space: nowrap; 
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;">{{ work.author_nickname }}</ion-card-subtitle>

        </ion-card-header>

        <div class="categories">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let category of work.genres">
            <ion-chip>
              <ion-label color="secondary">{{ category.name}}</ion-label>
            </ion-chip>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-card>
  <br>
</div>
```

Also my App performance is really slow. Look at the animation of the tabs when switching between them.

Here is a video for better understanding: https://youtu.be/J_Vl7D10uWY

I feel it's my book-card component what's causing the performance issue but I don't know why. Could it be because I have too many if statements to apply different classes or show different things?

Thanks!

Comment: If you deal with a large amount of data you might want to use Virtual Scroll from Angular CDK. Because, if that's the case you can have a real problem with rendering lots of data.

Comment: thanks for the tip @Sergey . didn't know about that and i'll surely use it!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as I suspected, the problem is my component and the usage of this library which was detecting any change on my view and recalculating ellipsis:

https://github.com/lentschi/ngx-ellipsis

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of this line

```
 response.forEach((work: Work) => this.works.push(work));
```

Define the return type from your sevice and just do this;

```
this.works = response;
```

Also, consider using trackBy with your ngFor loops when rendering large amount of data.

You can refer to this [arcticle](https://medium.com/better-programming/improving-angular-ngfor-performance-through-trackby-ae4cf943b878)

Comment: what alternative can I use for the foreach? I need to add items to the array, not to replace the existing ones...